# ActiveRecord: How to query all 'children_model' of 'parents_model' where 'parents_model.something = X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Community has_many posts

Posts belong_to Community

Community.featured is boolean

I want to retrieve all **Posts** where **Community.featured = true**

I've tried this, but I can't get the query to work: 
Community.joins(:post).where('community.featured=true')

Comment: Why did it not work? what issue are you facing ?

Comment: two things 1. if you want to fetch posts in result then you should query to post model 2. in your raw query(in the string) you should always use the plural form of the model because table names always be plural into the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems some typo, please try this -

```
Post.joins(:community).where("communities.featured= ?", true)
```

Or

```
Post.joins(:community).where(communities: {featured: true})
```

Note -  Always use `table_name` in `plural` form in the query i.e (`communities.featured` instead of `community.featured`)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using "includes" behalf of "joins" because If we go through Rails documenting, it clearly says — ‘With includes, Active Record ensures that all of the specified associations are loaded using the minimum possible number of queries’. When we need data to be used from associated tables, includes must be used.

```
Post.includes(:community).where(communities: {featured: true})
```

Or

You could write a scope in the Community Model

```
scope :show_featured_communities, -> {
  where(features: true)
}
```

And Call it as

```
Community.show_featured_communities.includes(:post)
```